# Exporting large files with Laravel-Excel (Exhausting memory size)

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, laravel-10

Is there a workaround to make large file exports work with Laravel-Excel (version 3.1)? All posts I saw here and on GitHub are old with no real solutions. The only solution is to increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini`. But I already have it at `2048M`.

Assuming I am using a collection:

```
class InvoicesExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Invoice::all();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it work? `WithChunkReading` is only for imports, and does not work for exports: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html#chunk-reading

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but in case someone else needs it. You can use `lazy` to limit consumed memory size.

```
public function collection()
{
    return Invoice::lazy();
}
```

**Other things you can do**

- Queuing
- Use a cache driver when memory is exceed

More info at [Laravel Excel Performance](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/4.x/exports/performance.html)

Answer (score -1):

Solution in 2023 :D

You can add few parameters to make it not use all the memory and crash the response

```
public function export($filename = 'users.xlsx') {
    try {
 
        $filename = !empty(request()->query('filename'))
            ? request()->query('filename') . '.xlsx'
            : $filename;
        // Adding uuid to filename avoid conflict can achieve the same result by adding timestamp
        $filename = Str::uuid()->toString() . '_' . $filename;
        (new InvoicesExport(<Insert your Args...>))->store($filename, 'local', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX, [
            'lazy' => true,
            'chunck_size' => 3000,
        ]);
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . $filename))
            ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->badRequest($e);
    }
}
```

By using `lazy` loading and adding `chunck_size` as disk options your are not using all the memory.

Comment: Please hint at the export class too like if you are using FromQuery concerns etc. Also I don't think passing lazy and chunk size in disk option has any way the export performs the chunks